# How to run apps in Kivy Launcher if the application uses additional modules?

Tags: python, kivy

I have created an app in Kivy.
It uses two modules: *requests* and *geocoder*.
How can I run this app by using Kivy Launcher?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install them manually into your project directory.
So if you need `Requests` for example, you can package it with the application.
You can download the source, copy the requests directory into your application’s codebase, and `import requests` in your python files as you normally would.